# C++ lock-free stack is corrupt

Tags: c++, stack, atomic, lock-free, corrupt

i am trying to implement a lockfree stack to be usable with external managed memory from a bounded plain c array. I know reference implementations (like from Anthony Williams: Concurrency in Action) and other books and blogs/article around the web.

The implementation follows those references and avoids the ABA problem, because external memory locations are addressed using unique indexes, rather than recycled pointers. Therefore it does not need to deal with mem managment at all and is simple.

I wrote some tests that execute pop and push operations on that stack under high load and contention (stress tests) and single threaded. The former fail with strange problems, that I do not understand and to me look obscure.

Maybe someone has an idea ?

1. Problem: Pushing an already popped node back to the stack fails, because precondition is violated that node has no successor (next).

   ```
   BOOST_ASSERT(!m_aData.m_aNodes[nNode-1].next);
   ```

   Reproduction setup: At least 3 threads and a capacity of ~16. Around 500 passes. Then push op fails.
2. Problem: Number of elements popped by all threads and number of elements left in stack after join do not match capacity (nodes lost in transition).

   ```
   BOOST_ASSERT(aNodes.size()+nPopped == nCapacity);
   ```

   Reproduction setup: 2 threads and capacity 2. Requires a lot of passes to occur, for me at least 700. After that head of stack is 0, but only one node is present in popped container. Node {2,0} is dangling.

I compiled with vs2005, vs2013 and vs2015. All have the same problem (vs2005 is also the reason that code looks C++03 like).

Here is the basic code for node+stack

```
template <typename sizeT> struct node
{
  sizeT         cur;  //!< construction invariant
  atomic<sizeT> next;
  atomic<sizeT> data;

  explicit node() // invalid node
    : cur(0), next(0), data(0)
  {}

  explicit node(sizeT const& nCur, sizeT const& nNext, sizeT const& nData)
    : cur(nCur), next(nNext), data(nData)
  {}

  node& operator=(node const& rhs)
  {
    cur  = rhs.cur;
    next.store(rhs.next.load(memory_order_relaxed));
    data.store(rhs.data.load(memory_order_relaxed));
    return *this;
  }
};

template <typename sizeT> struct stack
{
private:
  static memory_order const relaxed = memory_order_relaxed;
  atomic<sizeT> m_aHead;

public:
  explicit stack(sizeT const& nHead) : m_aHead(nHead) {}

  template <typename tagT, typename T, std::size_t N>
  typename enable_if<is_same<tagT,Synchronized>,sizeT>::type
  pop(T (&aNodes)[N])
  {
    sizeT nOldHead = m_aHead.load();

    for(;;)
    {
      if(!nOldHead) return 0;

      BOOST_ASSERT(nOldHead <= N);
      T& aOldHead = aNodes[nOldHead-1];
      sizeT const nNewHead = aOldHead.next.load(/*relaxed*/);
      BOOST_ASSERT(nNewHead <= N);
      sizeT const nExpected = nOldHead;

      if(m_aHead.compare_exchange_weak(nOldHead,nNewHead
        /*,std::memory_order_acquire,std::memory_order_relaxed*/))
      {
        BOOST_ASSERT(nExpected == nOldHead);

        // <--- from here on aOldHead is thread local ---> //
        aOldHead.next.store(0 /*,relaxed*/);

        return nOldHead;
      }

      // TODO: add back-off strategy under contention (use loop var)
    }
  }

  template <typename tagT, typename T, std::size_t N>
  typename enable_if<is_same<tagT,Synchronized>,void>::type
  push(T (&aNodes)[N], sizeT const& nNewHead)
  {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    {
      BOOST_ASSERT(0 < nNewHead && nNewHead <= N);
      sizeT const nNext = aNodes[nNewHead-1].next;
      BOOST_ASSERT(!nNext);
    }
#endif

    sizeT nOldHead = m_aHead.load(/*relaxed*/);

    for(;;)
    {
      aNodes[nNewHead-1].next.store(nOldHead /*,relaxed*/);
      sizeT const nExpected = nOldHead;
      BOOST_ASSERT(nOldHead <= N);

      if(m_aHead.compare_exchange_weak(nOldHead,nNewHead
        /*,std::memory_order_release,std::memory_order_relaxed*/))
      {
        BOOST_ASSERT(nExpected == nOldHead);
        return;
      }

      // TODO: add back-off strategy under contention (use loop var)
    }
  }
};
```

and the quite noisy test class

```
class StackTest
{
private:

  typedef boost::mpl::size_t<64> Capacity;
  //typedef boost::uint_t<static_log2_ceil<Capacity::value>::value>::least    size_type;
  typedef std::size_t size_type;

  static size_type const nCapacity = Capacity::value;
  static size_type const nNodes = Capacity::value;

  typedef node<size_type>  Node;
  typedef stack<size_type> Stack;

  typedef mt19937                                        Twister;
  typedef random::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t>  Distribution;
  typedef variate_generator<Twister,Distribution>        Die;

  struct Data //!< shared along threads
  {
    Node  m_aNodes[nNodes];
    Stack m_aStack;

    explicit Data() : m_aStack(nNodes)
    {
      m_aNodes[0] = Node(1,0,0); // tail of stack

      for(size_type i=1; i<nNodes; ++i)
      {
        m_aNodes[i] = Node(static_cast<size_type>(i+1),i,0);
      }
    }

    template <typename syncT>
    void Run(
      uuids::random_generator& aUUIDGen,
      std::size_t const&       nPasses,
      std::size_t const&       nThreads)
    {
      std::vector<ThreadLocalData>  aThreadLocalDatas(nThreads,ThreadLocalData(*this));

      {
        static std::size_t const N = 100000;
        Die aRepetition(Twister(hash_value(aUUIDGen())),Distribution(0,N));
        Die aAction(Twister(hash_value(aUUIDGen())),Distribution(0,1));

        for(std::size_t i=0; i<nThreads; ++i)
        {
          std::vector<bool>& aActions = aThreadLocalDatas[i].m_aActions;
          std::size_t const nRepetition = aRepetition();
          aActions.reserve(nRepetition);

          for(std::size_t k=0; k<nRepetition; ++k)
          {
            aActions.push_back(static_cast<bool>(aAction()));
          }
        }
      }

      std::size_t nPopped = 0;

      if(nThreads == 1)
      {
        std::size_t const i = 0;
        aThreadLocalDatas[i].Run<syncT>(i);
        nPopped += aThreadLocalDatas[i].m_aPopped.size();
      }
      else
      {
        std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<thread> > aThreads;
        aThreads.reserve(nThreads);

        for(std::size_t i=0; i<nThreads; ++i)
        {
          aThreads.push_back(boost::make_shared<thread>(boost::bind(&ThreadLocalData::Run<syncT>,&aThreadLocalDatas[i],i)));
        }

        for(std::size_t i=0; i<nThreads; ++i)
        {
          aThreads[i]->join();
          nPopped += aThreadLocalDatas[i].m_aPopped.size();
        }
      }

      std::vector<size_type> aNodes;
      aNodes.reserve(nCapacity);

      while(size_type const nNode = m_aStack.pop<syncT>(m_aNodes))
      {
        aNodes.push_back(nNode);
      }

      std::clog << dump(m_aNodes,4) << std::endl;

      BOOST_ASSERT(aNodes.size()+nPopped == nCapacity);
    }
  };


  struct ThreadLocalData //!< local to each thread
  {
    Data&                  m_aData;    //!< shared along threads
    std::vector<bool>      m_aActions; //!< either pop or push
    std::vector<size_type> m_aPopped;   //!< popp'ed nodes

    explicit ThreadLocalData(Data& aData)
      : m_aData(aData), m_aActions(), m_aPopped()
    {
      m_aPopped.reserve(nNodes);
    }

    template <typename syncT>
    void Run(std::size_t const& k)
    {
      BOOST_FOREACH(bool const& aAction, m_aActions)
      {
        if(aAction)
        {
          if(size_type const nNode = m_aData.m_aStack.pop<syncT>(m_aData.m_aNodes))
          {
            BOOST_ASSERT(!m_aData.m_aNodes[nNode-1].next);
            m_aPopped.push_back(nNode);
          }
        }
        else
        {
          if(!m_aPopped.empty())
          {
            size_type const nNode = m_aPopped.back();
            size_type const nNext = m_aData.m_aNodes[nNode-1].next;
            ASSERT_IF(!nNext,"nNext=" << nNext << " for " << m_aData.m_aNodes[nNode-1] << "\n\n" << dump(m_aData.m_aNodes));
            m_aData.m_aStack.push<syncT>(m_aData.m_aNodes,nNode);
            m_aPopped.pop_back();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };


  template <typename syncT>
  static void PushPop(
    uuids::random_generator& aUUIDGen,
    std::size_t const&       nPasses,
    std::size_t const&       nThreads)
  {
    BOOST_ASSERT(nThreads > 0);
    BOOST_ASSERT(nThreads == 1 || (is_same<syncT,Synchronized>::value));

    std::clog << BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION << " with threads=" << nThreads << std::endl;

    for(std::size_t nPass=0; nPass<nPasses; ++nPass)
    {
      std::ostringstream s;
      s << "  " << nPass << "/" << nPasses << ": ...";
      std::clog << s.str() << std::endl;

      Data().Run<syncT>(aUUIDGen,nPass,nThreads);
    }
  }

public:

  static void Run()
  {
    typedef StackTest self_t;

    uuids::random_generator aUUIDGen;

    static std::size_t const nMaxPasses = 1000;
    Die aPasses(Twister(hash_value(aUUIDGen())),Distribution(0,nMaxPasses));

    {
     //std::size_t const nThreads = 2; // thread::hardware_concurrency()+1;
      std::size_t const nThreads = thread::hardware_concurrency()+1;
      self_t().PushPop<Synchronized>(aUUIDGen,aPasses(),nThreads);
    }
  }
};
```

Here is a [link](https://cloud.gmx.net/ngcloud/external?locale=de&guestToken=KC36S0NESlmW39nVGUjhKQ&loginName=ingo.loehken@gmx.de) to download all required files.

Comment: For problem 1: Can you not set a node's `next` to `NULL` before returning it on pop?

Comment: That's exactly the strange thing. Next is set to 0, before returning from pop. Once again that node is pushed its next is not 0 anymore. Technically that's only possible, if another thread in the meantime modified that node again. But i do not see how it should be possible for another thread to access a popped node.

Comment: "The implementation follows those references and avoids the aba problem, because external memory locations are addressed using unique indexes, rather than recycled pointers." Um, the indexes are not unique. You still have an ABA problem.

Comment: Yes you are right. It just manifests in another way and is even more likely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Both problems are just another facet of the ABA problem.

stack: {2,1},{1,0}

1. Thread A

   1. pop
      new_head=1
      ... time slice exceeded
2. Thread B

   1. pop
      stack: {1,0}, popped: {2,0}
   2. pop
      stack: {}, popped: {2,0}, {1,0}
   3. push({2,0})
      stack: {2,0}
3. Thread A

   2. pop continued
      cmp_exch succeeds, because head is 2
      stack: {}, head=1 --- WRONG, 0 would be correct

Any problems may arise, because access to nodes is not thread local anymore. This includes unexpected modifications of next for popped nodes (problem 1) or lost nodes (problem 2).

head+next need to be modified in one cmp_exch to avoid that problem.